# Amazon EMR: Pyspark having strange dependency issues

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, pyspark, emr, amazon-emr

I have been having issues with getting a pyspark job to run on an EMR cluster, so I logged into the master node and ran spark-submit directly there

I have a python file that I submit to pyspark and in this file I have:

```
import subprocess
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
import boto3
from boto3.s3.transfer import S3Transfer
import os, re
import tarfile
import time
...
```

When I try to run this in cluster mode, I get:
(from yarn logs, trimmed for brevity)

```
16/01/31 21:45:57 INFO spark.CacheManager: Partition rdd_2_0 not found, computing it
16/01/31 21:45:57 INFO spark.CacheManager: Partition rdd_1_0 not found, computing it
16/01/31 21:45:57 ERROR executor.Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0)
org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/mnt1/yarn/usercache/hadoop/appcache/application_1454273602144_0005/container_1454273602144_0005_01_000002/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 98, in main
    command = pickleSer._read_with_length(infile)
  File "/mnt1/yarn/usercache/hadoop/appcache/application_1454273602144_0005/container_1454273602144_0005_01_000002/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 164, in _read_with_length
    return self.loads(obj)
  File "/mnt1/yarn/usercache/hadoop/appcache/application_1454273602144_0005/container_1454273602144_0005_01_000002/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 422, in loads
    return pickle.loads(obj)
ImportError: No module named boto3.s3.transfer

        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonRDD.scala:166)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.<init>(PythonRDD.scala:207)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner.compute(PythonRDD.scala:125)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:70)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:306)
        at org.apache.spark.CacheManager.getOrCompute(CacheManager.scala:69)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:268)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:70)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:306)
        at org.apache.spark.CacheManager.getOrCompute(CacheManager.scala:69)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:268)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:70)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:306)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:270)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:89)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:213)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Later on I get errors about being unable to import boto3.

If I run in client mode, I only get the ImportError about boto3.s3.transfer.

```
Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 0.0 (TID 3, ip-172-31-39-79.us-west-2.compute.internal): org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/mnt1/yarn/usercache/hadoop/appcache/application_1454273602144_0005/container_1454273602144_0005_01_000002/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 98, in main
    command = pickleSer._read_with_length(infile)
  File "/mnt1/yarn/usercache/hadoop/appcache/application_1454273602144_0005/container_1454273602144_0005_01_000002/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 164, in _read_with_length
    return self.loads(obj)
  File "/mnt1/yarn/usercache/hadoop/appcache/application_1454273602144_0005/container_1454273602144_0005_01_000002/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 422, in loads
    return pickle.loads(obj)
ImportError: No module named boto3.s3.transfer

    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonRDD.scala:166)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.<init>(PythonRDD.scala:207)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner.compute(PythonRDD.scala:125)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:306)
    at org.apache.spark.CacheManager.getOrCompute(CacheManager.scala:69)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:268)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:306)
    at org.apache.spark.CacheManager.getOrCompute(CacheManager.scala:69)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:268)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:306)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:270)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:89)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:213)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

However, if I check pip freeze:

```
boto3==1.2.3
botocore==1.3.23
```

If I open the Spark Shell on the master and do this:

```
import boto3
client = boto3.client("s3")
```

It works fine.

Is there some sort of virtual environment thing going on here? I'm totally confused.

**Edit**
Forgot to mention that I am using the latest EMR version with Spark 1.6.0.

Also, this works fine on my own machine in local mode.

Comment: Regardless to your question, consider using Spark's script for ec2 cluster launch instead of EMR.

Comment: @member555 I'd really rather not, the whole idea behind this project is the ease of provisioning this through EMR, and it is supposed to be supported. Sure I could do that, but then I have to use to the setup scripts and it is just more of a pain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, derp, I found the issue.

Turns out I had to `pip install boto3`, EMR nodes do not get this installed by default.

This is one case where the error is quite descriptive.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your python script you can call `pip`, like:

```py
import sys, subprocess
subprocess.check_call([sys.executable, "-m", "pip", "install", "boto3"])
import boto3
```